# Jmeter compose xml inside a controller

Tags: xml-parsing, jmeter

I have a foreach where I extract some value and I do a HTTP PUT.
Now I would like to don't call the PUT but compose the body in the foreach than at the end when I finish use the variable with all body for a unique HTTP PUT.

So Inside my foreach loop I have everything I need, but where can I write code? how Can I compose my variable?

My foreach is something like for every myarrays extract current value, so I should composy the body with that.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide some code

Comment: I don't have code yet, because I still need to find the way to write the code in jmeter

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Beanshell Pre Processor to write the java code.

You can use vars.put function to store your result into a jmeter variable.

Then you can use the jmeter variable in HTTP request.

Comment: I don't understand why I still have these errors when I try to use beanshell... I tried to resinstal from scrach jmeter.....                        ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Beanshell Interpreter not found 
ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellTestElement: Cannot find BeanShell: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: bsh.Interpreter

Comment: You can add beanshell processor from pre processors by right clicking request and write java code there.

Comment: I know. but as soon I add the preprocessor or post processor or whatever beanshell I have that error...and it doesn't work

Comment: Are you using latest versions.Please ty using 2.12 or 2.13. http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi

Comment: Yeah I tried with2.13 and also with another older version...the same result.. ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Beanshell Interpreter not found... Should I add some library? I don't find any solution on google, etc

Comment: But it is built in component. You can read here: https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell

Comment: Also check whether this jar is there, if not download and add https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/util/BeanShellInterpreter.html , your error seems to be because of this jar missing.

Comment: You can download all core jar files here including the one I specified and you can put it in lib folder: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/a/DownloadApacheJMetercorejar.htm .

Comment: I just put ApacheJMeter_core.jar in the folder apache-jmeter-2.13/lib. there are still the same errors

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at:

1. [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/) in general
2. [HTTPSamplerProxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSamplerProxy.html) in particular
3. [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for some examples on using JMeter and Java API from [Beanshell](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Sampler) test elements